# request-promise stack trace from catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I'm currently using 'request-promise' library for API calls from node-js, and struggling to get a correct call stack from the 'catch' function. After playing a bit with it, I noticed an interesting behavior which I can not explain. Say I have code:

```
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err.stack);
  console.log('!!!');
  console.log(new Error().stack);
});
```

And in the the console I actually see two totally different stack traces for the 'err' and 'new Error()' :

```
StatusCodeError: 404 - [object Object]
    at new StatusCodeError (C:\MyProject\request-promise\lib\errors.js:26:15)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (C:\MyProject\request-promise\lib\rp.js:68:32)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\request\request.js:187:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\request\request.js:1048:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\request\request.js:969:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
!!!
Error
    at C:/MyProject/src/server/controllers/bookingController.js:81:19
    at tryCatcher (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:584:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:700:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\MyProject\request-promise\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
```

As you can see, 'new Error()' gives more helpful info about the call stack, since it has

> 'C:/MyProject/src/server/controllers/bookingController.js'

I guess that is because 'err' exception was created with a previous tick, and therefore it's stack trace is not related to my 'bookingController.js' in any way.

Also, I see that 'request-promise' internally uses 'bluebird', so technically I could use Promise.longStackTraces().

Finally, my question: is there a smarter way to get a correct stack trace except using 'new Error().stack' trick, since Promise.longStackTraces() is too performace-heavy for production?

Comment: Of course you are getting different stack traces, because the two errors are created in very different places?

Comment: What do you get with `longStackTraces()` enabled? Yes, you probably should use them - they are explicitly meant for debugging, you wouldn't enable them in production of course.

Comment: @Bergi, Really? Oh wait, I mentioned that in my question. Actually, I hope to get an answer:  how achieve this without ugly 'new Error()'.

Comment: @Bergi I can not use longStackTraces() since it implies a substantial performance penalty.

Comment: If you want to get a trace for the error handler, not of the actual exception, then using `new Error().stack` is exactly the right thing to do (or you use one of those libraries that create nice pretty-formatted stack traces)

Comment: Why do you care about performance? You said you were only playing around anyway. What is the problem you are trying to solve that you need a stack trace for?

Comment: @Bergi, I need to log all request-promise exceptions to the logfile and cloud log storage. Eventually, solution will go to the production so performance matters.

Comment: And which information do you want to get in that log? The location of the `request.js` lib, the location of your global `catch` handler, or the location of the call to `request()`?

Comment: @Bergi, ideally - a location of the call to request(), e.g. something similar to what 'new Error()' shows.

Comment: For that, you *need* long stack traces. A `new Error` in the catch handler only will show you the location of the catch handler. Or you just put a local `.catch()` on every request call and annotate the errors manually.

Comment: @Bergi, damn, that's what I was afraid of. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, nodejs provides a prettier way to catch actual stack on nodeJS, which suits my needs:

```
  let capturedStack = {};
  Error.captureStackTrace(capturedStack, writeStack);
  console.log(capturedStack.stack);
```